# passing parameters to a bat (or vbs) in php

Tags: php, vbscript, batch-file

**Objective:** Use PHP to call a vbs that converts an xls/xlsx file to a csv.

**Question:** How can I pass a source file path and a destination file path to a vbs that converts xls/xlsx to csv and run that vbs in a PHP web application?

**Details:** I have a working vbs that takes a source file path and a destination file path and converts the xls/xlsx at source file path into a csv. I can execute it from the Windows cmd line and it  does exactly what I want it to do. I can also put the execution command into a bat file and run the bat file to achieve the same results. However, when I use exec()/shell_exec()/system() in PHP to execute the same command no csv is created. (If I try to run the bat from PHP using system() the contents of the bat file show up on the page, in fact, echo Conversion complete! prints "echo Conversion complete! Conversion complete.") I haven't seen any errors yet.

**Note:** I know about PHPExcel, I'd prefer not to use it.

**excelToCsv.vbs**

```
On Error Resume Next
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
Wscript.Quit
End If
csv_format = 6
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

**batConverter.bat**

```
excelToCsv.vbs conversionTestSourceMS2003.xls batTest.csv
echo Conversion Complete!
```

**index.phtml**

```
<?php
system("cmd /c batConvert.bat")
?>
```

**Note:** All of the above files (along with conversionTestSourceMS2003.xls) are in the same directory. I have not implemented any way to pass the parameters (since I can't get it to work even if it's all hard coded...)

**Set Up:** PHP5, Zend Framework, WAMP, Windows 7 (localhost).

Comment: Can you show us an example of the PHP you were using to execute the VBScript?  I'd like to see how you are specifying the path.

Comment: @jveazey Yep, that's **index.phtml** above, for now all that page has is a call to my bat file via `system()`. All of the files are in the same folder so the path _should_ be correct. I've also tried full paths (from C:) to no avail...

Comment: Is it necessary to use the batch file?

Comment: @jveazey Nope, I originally didn't have one, but tried it as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I merged everything into a single ASP page.  This will allow me to hopefully see a similar problem in IIS, and since it is in a single ASP script, I will be able to see the error more directly.  My test machine is running on Windows Vista SP2 on IIS7 with Excel 2007 SP3.

**excelToCsv.asp**

```
<%

Option Explicit

Dim csv_format, src_file, dest_file, strPath, objFSO

csv_format = 6
src_file = "conversionTestSourceMS2003.xls"
dest_file = "testbat.csv"

strPath = "[HARDCODED PATH HERE]\"
src_file = strPath & src_file
dest_file = strPath & dest_file

Dim objExcel, objBook
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
objBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
objBook.Close False

Response.Write "Conversion Complete!"
objExcel.Quit

%>
```

When running this code, I got a generic ASP error.  So, I enabled [detailed error messages in ASP](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2007/02/06/security-is-painful.aspx) and I get this following error...

> Microsoft Office Excel error '800a03ec'
>
> Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file '[HARDCODED PATH
>   HERE]\conversionTestSourceMS2003.xls'. There are several possible
>   reasons: • The file name or path does not exist. • The file is being
>   used by another program. • The workbook you are trying to save has the
>   same name as a currently open workbook.
>
> /temp/ExcelToCsv.asp, line 18

Now, this is not Apache, but I do believe the problem is related to yours.  This error implies there is a security/permission problem where Excel cannot do what it needs to do to access or read the file.  In fact, I encountered similar errors when I was executing the VBScript (and passing the error up the chain) from PHP (in IIS).

I believe it can be resolved by changing the Windows User being used to create the process.  This can be configured in Services.msc by editing the Apache service and changing the [Log On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tab to an actual Windows user instead of a Service Account.  I have not tested it yet, though, since setting up Apache is not something I can do right now.

Comment: I replaced my vbs and index with the ones you provided, and unfortunately still didn't get a csv. I didn't get any messages on the screen either. Did it work for you? Also, I'm (obviously) new to vbs so if there's an entirely different vbs method for achieving this objective I'm open to it. For instance, the files don't _need_ to be in the same directory, I just wanted to eliminate what I thought was a possible source of error. Thank you for your help! This problem is driving me insane.

Comment: @lostphilosopher I've updated my answer with a better way of diagnosing the problem.  Now, I don't know the exact security settings to use in DCOM, but that is where you'll need to deal with it.

Comment: I've just started working with your solution, but I thought I'd update you as I work through it. I went to Services.msc and found Apache2.2 and wampapache. I confirmed that wampapache is what I'm running and checked its "Log On As" tab. It is presently listed as "Local System account" with the alternative being "Network Service." I'm assuming this means it is configured correctly? I'll do some more research on users/log ons and I'll post if anything clicks.

Comment: Correction: Network Service is the only alternative _in use_. There is a "This account" option on the "Log On" tab where I'm assuming I could select a different user if I was to create one with the proper permissions. This is what I'll work on now.

Comment: Ok, tried that, no love. I created a new user (wampServiceAccount), made it the wampapache user, and gave it full permission to all program files, but I'm still not seeing a csv. (Or any errors.)

Comment: Try setting the user to the same one you used to log into Windows.  If you can run the VBScript manually, then this should allow you (or your user) to run the script through apache/php.

Comment: One thing I tried that gave me a little diagnostic information, was to remove the "On Error Resume Next" from the VBScript and add an echo "WScript.Echo" with a description of the subsequent line (or just the source code embedded in a string).  So, that when PHP runs the VBScript, the line that fails will be the last line that displays something on the web page.  You will need to run the VBScript directly from PHP - dropping the batch file, though.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work yet, so for now I'm just using some php libraries for the conversion. This seems to be the recommended method anyway, but I remain puzzled as to why the vbs/bat never worked. If anyone gets this working I'd love to see the code!